# Can anyone suggest some examples of using angular 2 release candidate animations?

Tags: angular

> I didn't find any Animation examples of how to add animations to a
>   project, should I add the logic in the controllers ?  If I add it in
>   the controllers is there a interface that should be implamented ? Also
>   some code examples would be really usefull since there is no
>   documentation yet :(

Comment: What kind of animation? AFAIK the animation module is not yet shipped.

Comment: for example animate a modal, I thought that is shipped since I can find him in the @angular/platform-browser

Comment: RC2 now includes animations: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html